# Posting formatted text into a textbox on a website

Tags: python, html, selenium, text, automation

1. I am parsing out a docx file and coverting it to html.
2. I am converting that html to json.
3. I am reading that json file, and i want to paste the contents of the file step by step.

It works fine, but i have formatted text in the json file, `<p> para </p>, <b> bold </b> etc.`

How do i paste formatted text, not plain text inside that textbox? The textbox doesn't recognize html.

I tried, this - `browser.execute_script(f'arguments[0].innerHTML = "{x["solution"]}"', solution)` but its not inside the textbox.

Comment: Arguments[0] has solution , what are you trying to do what is x?

Comment: @PDHide x is a dictionary/json object which contains the html

Comment: why do you think its available inside execute_scrpt ? its a sandbox where only document and the argument we pass are availble , here the arguent passed is solution . The value  solution can be accessed as arguments[0]

Comment: Leave that script that's what i tried in the past, now my question is abit different sir

Comment: some things just aren't going to translate... (<bold> for instance) but for line breaks and basic spacing you can insert into an iframe and then copy/paste.